# Executing batch script from ansible control host does not work properly

Tags: batch-file, ansible

I have following very simple batch script to install Visual Basic 2017 Build Tools.

```
C:\packages\visualstudio2017buildtools\vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.DataScience --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal --includeOptional --includeRecommended --noweb --quiet
```

When I execute this script locally on the server, everything works as expected while executing it from ansible control host does not install the software. Tried many things e.g. invoke script from ansible control host and also tried to execute it locally after copying it to the remote server. It looks like the script is executing and copies few dlls from the installer but never installs the actual software/components.

Any idea what I maybe missing?

Example ansible task:

```
- name: Invoke batch script to install Build Tools
  win_command: install.bat
  args:
    executable: cmd
    chdir: '{{ buildtools_dst_dir }}\visualstudio2017buildtools\'
    creates: '{{ buildtools_dst_dir }}\do_not_run_buildtools\'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
It looks like I was missing --wait parameter in batch script when running from ansible. Adding that solved the issue.